# Inheriting from a QListWidget and its SLOT

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, qlistwidget

Here is the class that inherits from `QListWidget`:

```
typedef void(*fnc) (QListWidgetItem* item);

class CustomListWidget : public QListWidget
{
public:
    CustomListWidget();
    void AddItemList(std::vector<std::string>* list);
    void ConnectToOnClickSlot(fnc func);
private:
    fnc onClick;
    void InvokeOnclickMethod(QListWidgetItem* item);
};
```

Corresponding .cpp file (part of it):

```
CustomListWidget::CustomListWidget()
{
    QObject::connect(this, SIGNAL(itemClicked(QListWidgetItem*)),
                     this, SLOT(InvokeOnclickMethod(QListWidgetItem*)));
}

void CustomListWidget::ConnectToOnClickSlot(fnc func)
{
    onClick = func;
}

void CustomListWidget::InvokeOnclickMethod(QListWidgetItem* item)
{
    onClick(item);
}
```

I was expecting that `InvokeOnclickMethod` to be called when items are clicked, but nothing happens. What might be the problem?

The main part:

```
auto listView = new CustomListWidget();
listView->ConnectToOnClickSlot(ItemClicked);

void ItemClicked(QListWidgetItem* item)
{
    //Do something...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `Q_OBJECT` macro for the class, where you want to use signals/slots. IIRC, the "old" connection also requires slots to be declared in `<accessibility> slots:` section.

By the way, people have been using the ["new" signal/slot connection syntax](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax) for about three years now.

Comment: Yep, solved the problem. Moreover, I was trying to connect **simple function** at the first place. Thus, you answered more than my question.